# Is the tensor algebra of the free vector space $Kx$ on one generator just the polynomial algebra $K[x]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, tensor-products

Let $K$ be a field and $Kx$ be the free $K$-vector space with basis $x$. Write the tensor product $x\otimes\cdots\otimes x$ as $x^n$. Then the tensor product of $n$ copies of $K\{x\}$ is $$(Kx)^{\otimes n}=Kx^n.$$ Then the tensor algebra of $Kx$ is $$T(Kx)=\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty Kx^n=K[x]$$ Is this right?

Comment: What makes you think this is incorrect? Do you think any part of your argument is incomplete or has a gap?

Comment: @Pedro I'm just a little unsure because I keep getting things wrong with tensor products and I haven't seen this result anywhere despite it looking like a fairly simple and important example of a tensor algebra.

Comment: There are two steps a bit hidden in your proof. Here $\otimes$ means $\otimes_K$. $T(Kx)=\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty K \underbrace{x\otimes \ldots \otimes x}_n$ so $x^n\mapsto \underbrace{x\otimes \ldots \otimes x}_n$ is an isomorphism of $K$-vector space $K[x]\to T(Kx)$, then you check that it is a ring homomorphism, thus a $K$-algebra isomorphism.

Comment: @reuns I think your comment (+a remark on whether the overall argument is correct) should be an answer.